# Getting Response From Jquery JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm having trouble getting a response from my php jquery / json / ajax. I keep combining all these different tutorials together but I still can't seem to pull it all together since no one tutorial follow what I'm trying to do.

Right now I'm trying to pass two arrays (since there's no easy way to pass associative arrays) to my jquery ajax function and just alert it out. Here's my code:

**PHP**

```
$names = array('john doe', 'jane doe');
$ids = array('123', '223');

$data['names'] = $names;
$data['ids'] = $ids;

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Jquery**

```
function getList(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", 
        url: 'test.php', 
        data: "",  
        complete: function(data){ 
            var test = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(test.names[0]);
            alert("here");
        }
    },
        "json");
}
getList();
```

In my html file all I'm really calling is my javascript file for debugging purposes. I know i'm returning an object but I'm getting an error with null values in my names section, and i'm not sure why. What am I missing?

My PHP file returns

```
{"names":["john doe","jane doe"],"ids":["123","223"]}
```

It seems to be just ending here 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` 
so my sub0 is killing me.

Comment: When I try to solve these problems, I split it into two: Server-side and client-side. Step 1: Is your server returning a JSON object in the format you're expecting? Try hitting /test.php in your browser and examine the JSON response. If that looks good, then output the JSON string in your JS callback.

Comment: I think that in $.ajax you have to set dataType: 'json'  instead of 'json' at end (how you do in $.get OR $.post )

Comment: my php file seems fine to me. How would I go about outputting my json to see how that looks besides an alert?

Comment: In your debugger, Firebug or Chrome dev, visit the NET tab and look for your request. In the "Response" or "JSON" section, you can see what the server sent back to the browser.

Comment: @kappa - The dataType isn't necessary if you convert the JSON manually; however, if what you say is true and it's automatically converted, that's awesome and something I must try!

Comment: A browser reserves the right to act funny if it doesn't get the content type when getting a php generated file (JSON, CSS, XML etc). You should always write this before your json_encode function: header('Content type: application/json'); This m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could prob use the `$.getJSON` facade that jQuery provides, this will setup all the required ajax params for a standard JSON request:

```
$.getJSON('test.php', function(response) {
    alert(response.names[0]);   // john doe
});
```

However i think the route of the issue is that 1) your server may not be returning the correct response codes and/or the correct headers (ie: JSON data) - however the above method at least for the latter should force this conclusion.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON

Comment: I thought you somehow wanted to keep $.ajax. Usually i use the $.get(....,'json')

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that you're using the complete callback instead of the success callback:

```
function getList(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", 
        url: 'test.php', 
        data: "",  
        success: function(data) { /* success callback */
            var test = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(test.names[0]);
            alert("here");
        }
    },
    "json");
}
getList();
```

From [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Docs:

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery wants to know what kind of data to expect as a response, otherwise it wont know how to parse it.

So, as has been said before here, you tell jQuery using the `dataType = 'json'` attribute.

```
function getList() {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", 
        url: 'test.php', 
        data: "",  
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

On top of this it is a good idea to have PHP present its content as json rather than html. You use the header for this by setting `header('Content-type: application/json');` before any output in your PHP script. So:

```
$names = array('john doe', 'jane doe');
$ids = array('123', '223');

$data['names'] = $names;
$data['ids'] = $ids;

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I'm still getting null values when I'm trying to access sub 0, I updated my question with what my PHP file outputs.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee even though it is working for you now, I fixed the above code and it should work with .ajax() now too.

Comment: @Mosselman - I I ran an ajax call both with and without dataType: 'json', and the callback still knew how to parse it out of the box. From the [jQuery Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), dataType:'json' is helpful in cases where jQuery can't use the mime type to determine the return type. In most cases, this isn't needed. This also wasn't the problem the OP faced. OP was using the "completed" callback instead of "success". Still, I think it's a good practice to include the dataType, both as fallback and communication clarity. +1 as this is all good information.

Comment: @jmort253 good to know about jquery using the mime type thanks. Hence it being a good idea to let PHP set the header then. I corrected my code to work since I had the same callback mistake, should have written the code myself. Late night coding is never a good idea. That should be the #1 tip on Stackoverflow!

Comment: @Mosselman +1 for updated answer, this works for me too now :3

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks :) glad it worked out after all. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass all parameters for ajax() function in single object. So, there should be "dataType" option. Also, if you set data type explicitly, jQuery will parse JSON data for you. Complete callback will receive parsed JavaScript object as parameter.

```
function getList() {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET", 
        url: 'test.php', 
        data: "",  
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(test) { 
            alert(test.names[0]);
            alert("here");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Good call on the dataType. However, I think the problem is that the complete callback doesn't include data from the server as the first parameter. I included a reference to the complete callback in my answer. If you change "complete" to "success", I am 100% confident your answer would be correct.